# Make a looping infinite scroll

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a scrollable `<div>` to contain a variable amount of items (2-20) that loop. I'd like to give it the appearance of a wheel, as in the iOS wheel selector [image]

I've searched about infinite scroll with jQuery but I only get results of the famous twitter and facebook functionality when it loads more content as you get closer to the bottom of the page. What I want is to replicate the items on the edges of the div, so that if you get closer to the bottom, items from the beggining would appear continually, without just appending more (it would get too big).

I am thinking about a way of doing this myself, without messing with the scroll when appending items at the beggining, but I'm sure there must be a plugin for this already.

Comment: When doing this with scroll, you just set the scrollTop to zero once you've reached the maximum scrollHeight, and it starts on the top again. It does'nt look like a wheel, nor does it work like the calender above, but you probably already knew that.

Comment: Back in C days, I'd accomplish this by feeding whatever UI I'd choose with a circular list of data... Maybe something similar can be done in modern days too ?

Comment: @adeneo I forgot to mention I'd love scrolling inertia... plus if there's just two items that don't even fill the `<div>` I want them to appear several times

Answer (score 0):

i think this is good for you .

http://jscroller.markusbordihn.de/

Comment: I think it's more oriented to replace a `<marquee>` instead of what I have in mind...

Comment: i think it's good for start , in previous version of it with clone of content and append after content and then start plugin  , i think it will be same as you want